# Discount factor taking into account yield curve shape

Tags: yield-curve, term-structure, discount-factor-curve, discounting

I have always been told that the discount factor formula is just:
$$
DF(T) = \frac{1}{(1+L_{t_0})^T}
$$
where $L_{t_0}$ is the LIBOR rate on one period (the first one I guess) and $T$ the number of periods.

But shouldn't we take into account the yield curve shape, and use instead forward rates:
$$
DF(T)=\frac{1}{(1+L_{t_0})\times \prod_{i=1}^T[1+F(t_i,t_{i+1})]}
$$
where $F(t_i,t_{i+1})$ is the forward LIBOR rate between start of period i $t_i$ and its end $t_{i+1}$?

Why haven't I encountered this? Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for an answer on another website, this formula is right.